# Qt GraphicsItem resize class

Tags: c++, qt

I try to write a class which handles the moving and resizing events of an object which is his parent.

```
QVariant ResizeItem::itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change,const QVariant &value){
```

`if (change == ItemPositionChange) {

       QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();

       qreal xV = round(newPos.x()/gridsize)*gridsize;
       qreal yV = round(newPos.y()/gridsize)*gridsize;

       parentItem()->setPos(mapToParent(QPointF(xV,yV)));
       QPointF pasdf = mapToParent(QPointF(xV,yV));
       QPointF poin7 = mapFromScene(pos());
       QPointF poin8 = mapFromScene(QPointF(xV,yV));
       QPointF point3 = mapToParent(pos())+QPointF(xV,yV);
       QPointF point = scenePos();
       QPointF pint5 = mapToParent(QPointF(xV,yV));
       QPointF point2 = mapToScene(xV,yV);
       QPointF point4 = mapToScene(pos());
       return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, pos()); // don't change position of item just position of parent

   }else{

       return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
   }`

}

When I move the parent Item from origin, everything works fine, but when I already moved the item and I would like to move again, in jumps back to the origin and moves from there the position I make with the mouse, with an offset between where the mouse is and the object.

Do anybody know whats my mistake?

The QPointF Variables are just temporary. I took them to have a look on the coords, if I find the mistake there.